# Problems in retrieving SP list

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am having a problem upon running my SP project. This is what i get. What might be the cause and how do i fix it?

[image]

Comment: did you read the error?

Comment: @Noctis what u mean by reading the error ? it should retrieve something when i type inside the textbox. Instead, this displays.

Comment: seems like you're missing a dll, or a reference ...

Comment: @Noctis i dont think so. Cos before this, it works perfectly. Now i just changed the service reference URL and this error came.